# What does the abbreviation "p.p." mean in the context of convergence

Tags: limits-and-convergence, mathematical-writing

What does the abbreviation "p.p." mean when referring to convergence? E.g. in [the following paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2037625) by Harry Pollard

> THEOREM. If $f \in L^p$ for some $p$ in the range $\tfrac{4}{3} <p < \infty$, then its Legendre
>   series converges **p.p**. The result fails if $1 <p<\tfrac{4}{3}$.
>
> [The Convergence Almost Everywhere of Legendre Series](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2037625), Harry Pollard

I am familiar with convergence a.s., a.e., in probability, in expectation, etc. Does this mean point-wise?

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe "presque partout"?

Comment: @MartinBright That looks sensible. Do post it as an answer.

Comment: just for fun, checking wikipedia pages in various languages: Catalan: **g.p.**,      gairebé pertot.

English: **a.e.**,     almost everywhere.  

French:  **p.p.**,     presque partout. 

German:   **f.ü.**,    fast überall.

Italian:  **q.o.**,    quasi ovunque.  

Polish:   **p.w.**     prawie wszędzie.
 
Russian:  **п.в.**,    почти всюду.

Spanish:  **c.t.p.**,  casi en todas partes. 

Swedish:  **n.ö.**,    nästan överallt. (...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to be an abbreviation for *presque partout*, meaning almost everywhere.  In the article you cite, reference is made to a paper of Hunt; the MathSciNet review for Hunt's paper (MR0236019) is in French, and begins

> Il s'agit d'améliorations substantielles apportées au théorème de Carleson sur la convergence presque partout des séries de Fourier...

Answer (score 2):

**p.p.** stands for "presque partout", french words that literally stand for ["almost everywhere"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere).

If you're in $L_p(E, \mu)$, this means that the given series converges on the whole domain $E$ but there may exist a subdomain $D \subset E$ with $\mu(D) = 0$ where the serie doesn't converge.

See [$L_p$ spaces on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000014-QINU%60%22'spaces).

Comment: I don't think it was necessary to downvote this, but note that your answer is practically identical to [one](https://mathoverflow.net/a/351971) given 9 hours earlier.